# Inserting an object into 2 Collections

Tags: java

I have 2 lists and am a little confused about adding an object into both of them like this:

```
TestClass e;
List lst1;
LinkedList lst2;
...
lst1.add(e);
lst2.add(e);
```

Will `lst1` and `lst2` have copies of `e`? or the reference to the same object `e`?
If the first is true, how can the code make copies of `e` if `TestClass` is not clonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Will `lst1` and `lst2` have copies of `e`?***

**Yes**.

Both lists will have *a copy of the value contained in `e`*. (Note though, that `e` contains a *reference* and not an actual object.)

This means that

1. Both lists will have one copy each of the reference to the `TestClass` object which `e` refers to at the point of the `add`.
2. Changes to the `TestClass` object will be visible from both lists references.
3. Performing `e = null` after the add will not affect the content of the lists (the lists contain copies, remember? ;-)

Comment: +1 Yes - this is more technically correct. I think the OP was thinking of `e` as being the object itself, when in reality it's the address to the object

Answer (score 2):

They will have the same reference. You will have to manually copy values over if you want it to be 2 distinct properties.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to - rather just wondering how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The second is true: both collections will hold a reference to that same object.

Answer (score 0):

This goes back to the old question of passing by reference vs passing by value...

See this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference/7034719#7034719)

Both `lst1` and `lst2` will contain a value (represented by the variable `e`) that will tell the JVM how to find the `TestClass` instance in the Heap Memory. If you modify the instance (there is only one instance) by accessing it through `e`, `lst1`, or `lst2` the changes will be visible everywhere!

The only way to change this behavior is to override the `Object clone()` in `TestClass` function and passing `e.clone()` to the `add(...)` function. Please refers to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)

If you cannot modify the `TestClass` for any reasons you can also clone the instance by yourself (basically you implement `clone()` outside `TestClass`). Create a new `TestClass` instance `e2` with the `new` operator and then get its instance variables *(be careful is it contains other custom objects)* from `e` through its 'getters' and set the values to `e2` through its 'setters'. This is ugly as hell and I hope you refuse to do it...